# Tomcat7 takes long time to deploy application

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7, digital-ocean

I have following setup for my server .

DigitalOcean Ubunutu14 box configure with Tomcat 7.

When I deploy an application it gets deployed fairly quickly, however, i am unable to access the app on (localhost:port/).Browser just hangs.

I am scratching my head on what could cause this? I waited for an hour and so,and checked back in and it worked fine.

Here is the log from catalina.out.

[localhost-startStop-1] INFO o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12833 ms